# Dask Memory leakage issue with json and requests

Tags: json, python-requests, dask, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

This is just a sample minimal test to reproduce memory leakage issue in remote Dask kubernetes cluster.

```
def load_geojson(pid):
    import requests
    import io
    r = requests.get("https://github.com/datasets/geo-countries/raw/master/data/countries.geojson")
    temp = r.json()
    import sys
    size_temp = sys.getsizeof(temp)
    del temp
    return size_temp

L_geojson = client.map(load_geojson, range(200))

del L_geojson
```

Observation: Steady increase in worker memory(Bytes Storage) by approx 30 MB on each run and keeps on increasing until whole memory is used.
Another test I tried with urllib, I observed there was a random increase and decrease in memory on each run.

Desired behavior: Memory should be cleaned up after the reference L_geojson is deleted.

Could someone please help with this memory leakage issue?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm an increase in memory and  "full garbage collections took X% CPU time recently" messages,. If I allow the futures to run, memory also increases, but more slowly.

Using `fsspec` does not have this problem, as you found with `urllib`, and this is what Dask typically uses for its IO (`fsspec` switched from `requests` to using `aiohttp` for communication).

Your modified function might look like

```
def load_geojson(pid):
    import fsspec
    import json
    fs = fsspec.filesystem("http"). # or use fsspec.open
    r = fs.cat("https://github.com/datasets/geo-countries/raw/master/data/countries.geojson"). # get bytes
    temp = json.loads(r)
    import sys
    size_temp = sys.getsizeof(temp)
    del temp
    return size_temp
```

but you still get garbage collection warnings.

Comment: With `fsspec`, I observed the memory increase wasn't steady and steep. But, if we run this for a large number of times(sample below), eventually whole memory is being used.
```for _ in range(100):
    L_geojson = client.map(load_geojson, range(200))
    L_res = client.gather(L_geojson)
    del L_geojson
    del L_res
```

Comment: garbage collection should be fine but at the end of the execution of multiple runs, I would expect the memory to be deallocated after multiple runs.

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried your code with `fsspec` but could not see any significant change. I'm observing this effect with much simpler code, as shown in the GIF. (It would be helpful to have a simple lineplot widget for some things over time in the Dask JL dashboard extension, instead of dynamic barcharts.)

[Dask memory issue GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEOgz.gif)

I wonder how much this is an issue in practice for long running clusters and applications? I know you can restart the cluster, but I don't know if this can be done in some smart way, like periodically when no tasks are running and/or are not scheduled yet. I wonder what people recommended?

In fact I've found this "lifetime" option which might work in practice although a runtime solution would be nice, too: [Memory clean up of Dask workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802296/memory-clean-up-of-dask-workers). I wonder how this is handled in large cluster installations working on a Tera-/Petabyte scale?